# Date Format Issue with Web service

Tags: c#, web-services, date

I have a web service with input parameters.  The relevant XSD in the WSDL is below

[image]

When I added this WSDL as Service Reference in Visual Studio, it generated a class with the corresponding fields as`System.DateTime`.  Below is an example of the field in Reference class added for WSDL

```
private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> startDateField;
```

My binding to the service to create client is CustomBinding below

```
 protected CustomBinding GetCustomBinding()
    {
        var customBinding = new CustomBinding() { Name = "CustomBinding" };

        customBinding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement() { MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11 });
        var securityBindingElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
        securityBindingElement.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
        securityBindingElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
        securityBindingElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;
        customBinding.Elements.Add(securityBindingElement);
        customBinding.Elements.Add(new HttpTransportBindingElement());

        return customBinding;
    }
```

My c# code to assign input

```
myobject.input.endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate);
```

After assigning input values, I called a web method to see in `Fiddler` that all date parameters are missing in Request.

I tried to test in SoapUI. It looks like the service expects date in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` though the type is of date.  The webservice returns data only when I supply date in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

I'm not sure if it is something to do with the expected date format by web service.  Obviously, I can't send in format yyyy-MM-dd as .Net generated reference class has `DateTime` but not `string` data type.

I tried to forcibly set `Specified` to true

```
myobject.input.endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).Date;
myobject.input.endDateSpecified = true;
```

I got the below error:

```
A value was being set that exceeded the maximum allowable field length.
```

Now, I suspect that the web service expects Date but .Net is trying to send DateTime which might be extending its length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like my last code worked but the error was due to another field.

```
myobject.input.endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).Date;
myobject.input.endDateSpecified = true;
```